# Reading from Keysight Scope to MATLAB

Tags: oscilloscope, matlab

I have a DSO-S 104A scope. I have it connected through a USB 3.0 cable to a PC with MATLAB. I want MATLAB to read the waveform from the scope into a vector. I'm sampling packets of pulses, the frequency of the packets is 10 KHz. Currently I'm using the following code:

```
h=1;  %Number of packets to sample (from 1 to 10K)    
for k=1:h
  empty=0;
  data0 = query(scop1, 'WAVeform:DATA?');
  r=0;

  while not(empty)
    data1=fscanf(scop1);
    empty=isempty(data1);
    data0 = sprintf('%s%s', data0,data1);
    r=r+1;
  end

  Data=str2num(data0);
  DATA(:,k)=Data;
end
```

This reads each point on the scope and assembles them into a string, which is then converted into a vector. My issue is that this process is incredibly slow. At the packets rate of 10 KHz to obtain an acceptable resolution I need to sample at least 3000 packets, and at the speed that I'm currently doing it it will take an hour at least. 
Does anybody have a better way to read from a scope?

Comment: You could preview the question before posting, I'm not sure what's happening but it looks like half your code is code and some parts is not?

Comment: If this exchange has any forum related to programming, put this question there, because your electrical interface is working, you are getting data onto MATLAB. you need to vectorize your code. Ask on correct forum.

Comment: Are you opening a new connections for every query?

Comment: It seems the "query" command includes the ability to convert the received data - you need to give it a conversion for "rformat" and probably for "wformat."  Might be faster than what you are doing.

Comment: I'd highly recommend giving your local Keysight support center a call. They're super helpful! www.keysight.com/find/contactus